# Increase the maximum return limit for WFS layer on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, wfs

I would like to add [this layer](https://lris.scinfo.org.nz/layer/104400-lcdb-v50-land-cover-database-version-50-mainland-new-zealand/) to a ArcGIS Online map.

As you can see there are millions of records. I tried adding it as a WFS layer but the maximum features it can return is about 3000. I tried adjusting the Visible Range to a bigger scale but still it won't refresh. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't. To be clear, you will never be able to display all these features from a WFS. No browser can deal with displaying on client side millions of polygons. You need to consume the layer as an image. The limitation to 3000 is not for nothing.

On the link you provide, I've explored their site. Follow this exact link https://lris.scinfo.org.nz/layer/104400-lcdb-v50-land-cover-database-version-50-mainland-new-zealand/data/2426587/?mt=Streets&l=104400&lpw=650&cv=0&z=16&c=-41.48472%2C172.42894&e=0&al=m

They display a feature using this URL https://lris.scinfo.org.nz/services/query/v1/feature.dojodata/104400/?v=1.3&key=60f55bab5e3c44dc980bb1595fac0d7d&query=%7B%22__pk__%22%3A2426587%7D&include_geom=true&start=0

and below they use a background image of all the features from "LCDB v5.0 - Land Cover Database version 5.0, Mainland New Zealand" but to not overload the map using tiles e.g https://tiles-b.koordinates.com/services;key=60f55bab5e3c44dc980bb1595fac0d7d/tiles/v4/layer=104400,style=auto,color=003399/16/64157/41082.png

It's an image, it's not a WFS. As you can see, they do not display all features as WFS as they know it limitation for this use case.

After this critique, what can you do to solve the issue? You need to download the data from their website and publish it to serve as an image using a WMS, a WMTS (both are OGC services) or in "ArcGIS world", an ArcGIS Map Service Layer or an ArcGIS ImageServer layer.
From these services, you will be able to consume/see all the data in your ArcGIS Online map, something not possible with WFS approach.

Comment: how did you find out the two links you pasted in your answer?

Comment: Network panel from the browser Dev Tools. For Chrome, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/, Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor, Edge https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/network/  In general, open the Devtool Network Panel, reload current page (in this case the URL I provided) and see/inspect network calls.

Comment: Will I still be able to see attributes when I click on the feature if I use WMS / WMTS / ArcGIS world?

Comment: WMS yes, WMTS only if the provider behind is WMS and let you make query behind the scene. See demo of https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html (it's called a "GetFeatureInfo") For the others in ArcGIS, I think so but not 100% sure as I'm doing more opensource stuff, less familiar with ESRI/ArcGIS products and services